# java downcast results in method not applicable error

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to downcast a function for my database objects.  I get:

> The method GetAsStringArray(HashMap<Long,dbObject>) in the type
>   dbObject is not applicable for the arguments
>   (HashMap<Long,dbEmployee>)

when I try to call GetAsStringArray().  Here is my test code:
dbObject base class:

```
public class dbObject  implements Comparable<dbObject> {
    protected long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static dbObject[] GetAsArray(HashMap<Long,dbObject> map) {
        Collection<dbObject> list = map.values();
        dbObject[] ar = list.toArray(new dbObject[] {});
        Arrays.sort(ar);
        return ar;
    }

    public static String[] GetAsStringArray(HashMap<Long,dbObject> map) {
        Vector<String>vStrings = new Vector<String>();
        Collection<dbObject> list = map.values();
        dbObject[] ar = list.toArray(new dbObject[] {});
        Arrays.sort(ar);
        for (dbObject o : ar)
            vStrings.add(o.toString());
        return (String[]) vStrings.toArray(new String[] {});
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(dbObject another) {
        return (int)(this.getId() - another.getId());
    }

}
```

Child class dbEmployee:

```
public class dbEmployee extends dbObject {
    private String First;
    private String Last;

    public dbEmployee(){}

    public String toString() {
        return Last + ", " + First;
    }
}
```

And the error:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    HashMap<Long,dbEmployee>mapEmployees = new HashMap<Long,dbEmployee>();
    dbEmployee.GetAsStringArray(mapEmployees);
}
```

*Note: some of my dbObjects will have their own compareTo() function (a few of the objects have a field in the db to override the default sort order), but most of the items just sort by id.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to redefine the method thusly:

```
public static dbObject[] GetAsArray(HashMap<Long, ? extends dbObject> map) {
    Collection<? extends dbObject> list = map.values();
    dbObject[] ar = list.toArray(new dbObject[] {});
    Arrays.sort(ar);
    return ar;
}
```

A `Map<Long, dbEmployee>` cannot be used in place of a `Map<Long, dbObject>`, because although it has some of the same behaviour, some of its behaviour is very different. In particular, you can't *add* an Object of type `dbObject` to a `Map<Long, dbEmployee>`.

If the method `GetAsArray(HashMap<Long, dbObject> map)` allowed you to pass it a `Map<Long, dbEmployee>`, you would be able to add `dbObjects` to the map from inside the method. The method has no way to know that the map is not actually a map of `dbObjects`. Then, if you held on to a reference to the map outside of the method, you would have big problems. The map would no longer by type-safe. It would say it was a `Map<Long, dbEmployee>`, but it would actually contain `dbObjects` that were *not* `dbEmployees`.

The `? extends dbObject` syntax allows you to specify what you can get *out* of the map without detailing what can go in it. You'll notice that if you now try to add something to the map inside the `GetAsArray(HashMap<Long, extends dbObject> map)` method, you'll get a compile error.

(There is an equivalent syntax, `? super dbEmployee`, that would let you put things in the map without knowing what could come out).